# Android Studio : How to change Language on Emulator Android studio Bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I recently upgraded to latest android studio Bumblebee and I want to change the emulator language.

I know of an approach before which is

> Open menu -> Setting -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Locale

but when I tried to open settings, I can't see option for **Language & Keyboard **

Do I need to configure anything?

[image]

Comment: language of emulator's internal language or talking about the emulator's outer settings window?

Comment: the emulator device language